# Challenging combinatorial problem possibly involving Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This problem was given as an add-on on to a homework problem in a discrete math class:

There are $k$ number of weights. Each of them weighs either $1,2,3,4,...,2k$ grams (no repeats). Find the minimum value for $k$ such that when given any combination of weights, we can put a non-zero number of weights on a balance scale and the scale is balanced. (i.e. we can find 2 sets of numbers between 1 and 2k such that the sum of all the numbers are equal).

I found out that the minimum value is 5 but how do we prove it? I tried using the Pigeonhole principle since it was taught in class recently but I also suspect that it could be using the fact that $2^k-1 > 2k$ when $k = 5$. Because you can try to pick a contradicting set of numbers by picking $1, 2, 4, 8,..., 2^n$.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. First, do you mean the weights can be in the range 1,..,2k? Also, can they repeat? Also, also, does the question want us to use all the weights or some of them? Please try to clean this up.

Comment: Hello BBischof. Sorry I missed that part out. The question would be so much easier without that extra restriction though!

Comment: Are you sure that k = 5 is the answer?

Comment: Yea pretty much convinced actually.

Answer (score 1):

The way to prove it is first to show it must be at least $5$ by displaying $1,2,4,8$ as a set with $k=4$ that fails to have a solution, then to show that any $5$ numbers out of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,10\}$ have two subsets that balance.  If $1$ and $2$ are both included, the other three will have a pair with difference $3$ or less and a balance can be achieved.  If $1$ is included and $2$ is not, the only choices that do not have a pair of neighbors are $\{3,5,7,9\}, \{3,5,7,10\}, \{3,6,8,10\}, \{4,6,8,10\}$ and you can show a balancing set for each.  I'll let you do the cases with $2$ and without $2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does this mean we have to manually check all the cases? (after narrowing it down considerably)

Comment: I don't see a nice way to avoid checking a bunch of cases.  Sometimes there is a choice between checking cases and logical narrowing.  As ${10 \choose 5}=252$, there aren't *that* many to check even without narrowing.  I took the ones I could see easily.